# Build not visible in itunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I want to test in app purchases therefore I uploaded build with xcode. I can see the build under "Prerelase" but not in "Versions". How long does it take to show up in "Versions"? It's been 30 minutes

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The build is not visible until the "Processing" step is in progress in the "Prerelease" tab. 
It should depends on the size of your app. 
For a 10Mb app of mine, it took about 5 min.

Comment: Since the last months, you get an email from Apple Developer when the "processing" has ended. I just had to be patient

Comment: 1 hour waiting here.

Comment: After uploading my build  not visible in processing state in activity tab. when I upload same version again it prompts build is already available.

Comment: 72 hours here, for a 9 MB file.

Comment: Not sure if this is just a coincidence, but waited hours refreshing email and iTunes connect and then decided to just try the upload again. Got the expected duplicate binary version error upon upload but then immediately got an email that the app had finished processing and it shows up in iTunes connect!

Comment: I have uploaded built like 3 months back and until now it s not giving me the file.Or It is accepting new builds which i submit.Do we have any solution for this.Asap thanks in advance.

Comment: @venki I don't understand your question, if you want to submit a new build for a release, you need to increase the build number (a.k.a "Bundle version" in Info.plist) and create a new Archive of your project to be able to upload a new version. Was it your question ?

Comment: I have checked the issue is different.Its working now.

Comment: Now it's showing in `Activity` Tab -> `All Builds`.

Comment: If you're impatient like me - if Xcode gives the `Uploaded` success message, then there is a definitive **2-3min** wait time before **anything** shows up in the Builds section of AppStore Connect

Comment: After around hours of wait still not available on itunesConnect

Answer (score 123):

Check your inbox for an email from iTunes Store:

> Subject: iTunes Connect: Your app [...] has one or more issues
>
> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
> [your app]. To process your delivery, the
> following issues must be corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
> description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
> the user how the app uses this data.
>
> [...]
>
> Once the required corrections have been made, you can then redeliver
> the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Xcode 8 told me the upload was successful, but the build did not appear in iTunes Connect until I fixed the issues indicated in the email and resubmitted.

Comment: Also don't forget 'Privacy - Contacts Usage Description'

Comment: Same issue.  You think the build would go from processing to failed, rather than processing to nothing

Comment: A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'xxxxx'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key.

Thanks

Answer (score 56):

May be helpful:

1. While pushing build to ITunes, i minimize organzier window, so in background everything went smoothly and message got display "Build pushed successfully".
2. But build do not got display in itunes store and sometime build get display in "Processing" step but do not get to "Versions".
3. I repeated step 1 and 2 but same result.
4. Then i pushed build with **Organizer window (in Foreground) not Minimised and everything worked**. (It takes some time according to size as  @cdescours pointed)
5. This experiment was conducted on dated 30, Oct, 2014 throughout day & also same issue was discovered later too. Hence we can conclude iTunes have the issue when the build is pushed in background.

Comment: I did it and works today (02/2016). I'm using XCode 6.4

Comment: This also helped me (04/2016). Using XCode 7.3.
This is really weird (to say the least).

Comment: This works. Another reason Apple need to fix iTunes Connect.

Comment: This is still valid for Xcode 8. I uploaded my macOS app 5 times today and every time I hid Xcode (Cmd+H) to work on something else. Even though Xcode said "Upload completed", the builds never appeared in iTunes connect in the Activity tab. Then after reading this I tried to leave Xcode in the foreground while it was uploading, and then the build immediately appeared in iTunes connect as "Processing".

Comment: Minimizing cancels the upload, but says it's successful even though it is not. See comment in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37461052/237509

Comment: Wow, WTF!? This also worked for me. I'm super surprised that this made a difference.

Comment: Xcode 10.3. Keep uploader in the foreground and it worked for me.

Answer (score 37):

To update @cdescours' answer, uploaded builds can now be seen in the "Activity" tab in "Processing" state.

Comment: In my experience the problematic build showed as 'Processing' for all of the 4 minutes that it was being analyzed, and then just mysteriously disappeared from the list. No 'Failed' entry, no error message, no hint of what happened, no nothing. _Of course_ its in your email if you only know to check it.

Answer (score 37):

Check the Activity tab in iTunes Connect after you upload the app and wait until it processes:

[image]

Comment: After procesing, the build didn't appear in the list. What the solution?

Comment: If you make some mistakes, the system is unforgiving. Your upload is successful but it does not appear in this list. (In fact, the success means that you have used that build number). You have to check your email for the error. The build number will never appear in any way in the iTunes Connect website.

Answer (score 21):

Check your email. You should have issue or missing report on you email. I got email that I miss `NSCameraUsageDescription` key in `Info.plist`

[image]

Comment: I would have wasted days

Answer (score 16):

When you upload your build from Application loader or directly from your xcode to App Store and it is not showing even on multiple uploads with different build version then

1. Open your .plist file and check whether there is any key string starting with "Privacy - ........."
2. If that **key** string value is empty, then Add some string.
   example, for me i was using camera, photo Library, Microphone and Location.
   For my project i added the string as follows
   a. This app requires access to the Camera.
   b. This app requires access to the Photo Library.
   c. This app requires access to Microphone of your device.
   d. This app requires access to your Location.
   e. This app requires access to the Bluetooth.
3. Now upload the build it will get Accepted.

Note: This permission string is mandatory from iOS 10.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was all the "Privacy - ..." keys had an empty string. `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, `NSCameraUsageDescription`, `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`.

Comment: You are a life saver. Glad I didn't have to Google each key in my plist to figure out what was wrong, I was just missing a Photo permissions description.

Answer (score 15):

In case you are adding build with deployment target >9, add these keys to info.plist in case you are using camera and photos: `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` and `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` with a valid description.

I had the same issue when I submitted with blank string for these keys.

Comment: Where to add these detail?

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi in info.plist.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes you may need to check your email. There will be no errors while uploading. But apple may have send an email with the errors in your build. In my case I got an email with the following error mentioned in it.

```
This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

I have added the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key, but the description string was empty.

Comment: Yeah. Cause that's how advanced Apple error reporting is.

Comment: Yeah right? Hey Apple 1996 called and wants its workflow back.

Answer (score 11):

[image]
You can see all of your activities (recently uploaded builds here). It will also provide current status of your build.

Answer (score 6):

Building on @sreedeep-kesav's answer (not enough rep to comment), `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` and `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` can be set by opening your `Info.plist` file in Xcode and selecting the plus button next to `Information Property List`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Wow this was super annoying! Honestly I don't know what the problem was because I've uploaded many apps to the appstore via Xcode over the past few years but past couple days I tried like 8 different build uploads over span of 12 hours but NONE of them would show up in iTunesConnect as Processing or anywhere else. I eventually tried [Application Loader](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/) even though I've NEVER had to use that before. The first try timed out "Fetching Apple Connect token" or something. I CMD+Q and tried Application Loader again and the 2nd time the upload finished ... and *now* my build shows up in iTunesConnect as processing. OMG that was annoying, confusing and a huge waste of time (typical Apple Dev experience I guess).

Anyhow ... thought I would share my results.

Comment: Wow I spoke too soon. I saw my build in iTunesConnect immediately after Application Loader succeeded but now it has disappeared and no longer shows up in iTunesConnect. I haven't received any emails from Apple either. What in the world is going on!

Comment: Finally spoke with Apple on the phone. This was the problem w/the app - but the Apple servers weren't emailing me about it so the only way to find out was to call them. Super annoying!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566952/cordova-info-plist-nscamerausagedescription-key-is-missing

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue, once I upload build is not showing in `AppStore Connect` even I did not get any issue mail from apple. So I just wait for a day and that build begins visible on `AppStore Connect` after a day. It is a weird issue apple team have to look into it.

Happy coding. :)

Comment: It would be helpful if the system tells us this so we don't know we're doing something wrong. I'll keep checking, maybe tomorrow by the sounds of it.

Answer (score 2):

Check your all privacy access policy option in Info.plist file.

Answer (score 2):

Check the status of the new build on the "**Activity**" tab. Once the "**Processing**" label disappears from the build you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Check your schema that you have selected release not debug.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issues, i switched from Xcode6.0 to Xcode6.1 and my builds started appearing in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my expereince, 
I uploaded my build by application uploader and xcode and after 10 hours i couldn't see any build on the itunes connect.
Finally I contacted apple and they explained that a build validation can take 24 hours maximum.
After 24 hours, if the build is not visible on the related page, they advise to upload a newer version. 
And if after the second 24 hours if there is still not any build, you can call apple developper program assistance.
Here is the page where you can find phone numbers :

https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

Publishing the first version of your application can takes a few days but a newer version takes much less time.

Answer (score 1):

Check all the **key and values in info.plist** file.
if any key is missing then it will cause this issue.
AppIcon and other thing written in info.plist file must be prefect then u will not able to get this issue.

Comment: There is already an answer that solved the issue. Please have a look at this one.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

If build are missing from Itunes 'Activity' tab. Then check your info.plist keys. If all keys are there, then check all keys description. if their length is short then increase your keys description length.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my experience as well. My Build had crossed Processing Step(it was a mere 984kB app) but did not show up in "Versions" tab for more than 30 minutes. I also double checked my email but had not received anything from Apple. However, under versions tab I had 3 builds listed excluding the latest one. What worked for me was that I just clicked on the least recent one(click on the Build Number) and then clicked on Expire Build and voila buy recent Build was immediately available under the current Version.

I have not found any Apple Document which explains this anomaly.

Hope it Helps! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case I uploaded a build with updated version. like `1.1.0` *Build* `1.1.0`, then I reverted back to `1.0.0` build `1.0.5` and the same build was visible under the **`1.0.0`** header dropdown.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**This was My Mistake:**

I had a minor update in a Push Notification content part and I did not even touch my code.

But I thought I might have to re-upload it in order to reflect that change in the latest version.

And I did.

Tried to upload 3 Builds One by One.

But Not a single build has shown in the Test Flight Version.**(Shocked)**

Later I realized my mistake that just by updating APNS content part without even touching my code, I was trying to upload a new build and was expecting to reflect it in the Test Flight. **(So stupid of me)**

Answer (score 0):

InFeb 2020, Apple has changed the TestFlight upload policy. When you do the same old steps to upload your app to TestFlight, even though you provided the export compliance information and the iOS Buildpage shows your build is ready to test, it just doesn’t show up on the TestFlight app. That’s very weird right?
After googling and browsing the StackOverflow threads, it turns out you need to add an extra row in info.plist to make it work.

```
App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption = NO
```

info.plist
This way it’ll magically work.
And you don’t even need to provide the export compliance information every-time you upload a new build too!

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue. Issue was resolved for me by trying to distribute the archive again through Xcode. At the final stage it showed the error that an app with the same version number had already been uploaded (my initial upload an hour ago). As soon as that error message showed I got the email that the original build was available in App Store connect. There must be a workflow issue in the upload process.