# Upload build to iTunes Connect issue

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store, application-loader, xcode6.3.1

I am uploading new build on iTunes Connect via Xcode. I've selected all my settings automatically I mean about provisioning profiles and certificates, so the bundle id is also appropriate.

After I clicked submit to app store button, the Xcode build loader displayed for me all entitlements setting, and displayed that it uses app store distribution certificate (which is correct, because I use automatic settings for signing.)

After some time, the Xcode build loader said that everything is successes and the build on the iTunes, but I don't see it in my prerelease tab, I can say it will be better if loader said "suckesses" instead of successes. So it appeared for me many times when I uploaded new build with new build number but there are no new builds on iTunes.

Also I tried to upload build number 4, because I already have 3 builds under prerelease section, but without success. So I bump build to 10 and voila it's on the iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the build, it will take some time to appear in itunes. So we have to wait for sometime to appear in appstore.

Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784313/build-not-visible-in-itunes-connect) for your reference

Comment: =) ok can it takes 2 weeks? because I uploaded 4th build 2 weeks ago, there is no build yet for testing with build number 4

Comment: No it donot take that much time.