# Itunes Connect: Can't See Build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

After submitting my app through Xcode, I see my app with no icon and it says "Uploaded" in the prerelease tab. What should I do? It's been two hours. I validated and submitted without any issues through Xcode. Here's what I see:

[image]

**Update**:
It's been about another 2 hours and I still see:

[image]

**Update #2**:
It's been another 24 hours and nothing!

**Update #3**:
I've contacted iTunes Connect Support addressing this issue and they said they would give me a call after they get in touch with the engineers. Here is what they said through email:

> I will follow up with you as soon as I have an update. Thank you for
>   your assistance and continued patience.

**Final Update! SOLVED!**
After a drastic 5 days of just getting this app to review, they've finally fixed the issue. It seemed to be an issue with the server. The best help I can give to those stuck is to try to send another build or [contact iTunes Connect Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php)(it's faster to call then to email). Also, if you get your app sent to review, don't forget to request an expedited review from Apple, to make the review process faster (not every one is guaranteed). Thanks so much for all of your support!

Comment: The x.x notation seems odd for a build number to me. I use x.x.x for my version numbers and just x for my build numbers and it works well. But if Apple doesn't reject it at Xcode validation I guess it's okay... but still odd.

Comment: @QuentinHayot Could it be something wrong with my build settings? I put in all of my distribution certificates under code signing as well the correct provisioning profile,

Comment: Submitting builds through itunes connect is really obnoxious. Aggghh

Comment: This seem to be a recent problem. I submitted my app on Sept 20th and it's still 'Processin'. Please update if you find solution.

Comment: @nanospeck I'll keep you all updated.

Comment: New Update. Check the edits.

Comment: I have same issue.Can any one tell me why this happens??

Comment: Just wait a month then it should appear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wait more. It will be processed eventually.
Apple may have issues with their validation servers or could have a very long pending apps queue. Just be patient.

**Edit:** (from [MGame's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3859020/mgames) experience)
If after a few hours, your build still hasn't started being processed, give a [phone call to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php). It seems that in some rare case your app could get stuck in their servers and they have to manually resolve the issue.

Comment: At least this clears the fact that it isn't processed yet. How long do you think it'll take?

Comment: Not too long hopefully ;) I noticed the delay on friday already.

Comment: I sent it at 7:10ish. I guess I'll wait a couple of hours then. But, it makes me happy to know that this world is filled with devs!

Comment: So? Did it finally got processed?

Comment: Not yet. It still says uploaded. Is this normal?

Comment: Not really. but there is not much you can do. I guess we'll have to wait for monday before they can fix it.

Comment: Yep! That's a business day and tomorrow I'll try to contact them.

Comment: I contacted ITunes connect support and they told me to submit a new build again. I'll do it in a couple of hours and let you know what happens.

Comment: Great to hear! Looks like my guessing was right after all, even Apple can have server issues :')

Comment: Yes! But, the person I was contacting had to contact the apple engineers to fix this. It's happening with a lot of people. A quick call to iTunes Connect Support would notify them about this issue. They'll fix it in a couple of hours, depending on your situation.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the phone call solution for the next poor victim/

Comment: Which is why this is now the solution! :)

Comment: Mine's been 18 hours. I submitted 4 builds and none shows up (I already check the Activity tab).

Comment: Just submit another build..., my previous build is still missing

Answer (score 12):

Please check your email inbox.This may be the issue

"Dear developer, We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "App Name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected: Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0. Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro. Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0. Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Comment: Thanks for your mail box hint

Answer (score 5):

I have the same trouble. I tried the following:

1. Increase the second build number

[image]

2. Resubmit binary

Then my app process was completed immediately.

Answer (score 3):

After waiting for a week without seeing builds, I've try Application Loader from Xcode 8.1beta.
Steps:

- **Archive**
- **Export** -> **Save for iOS App Store Deployment** -> Save a folder with IPA in my desktop
- **Xcode** -> **Open developer tools** -> **Application Loader** -> choose IPA file from desktop

Now I can see my builds..

Answer (score 3):

I have added myself as App Manager and Got email that i need to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist. For more Details see this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39650451/1394622

But as i am writing this answer also working for people. It says just don't put xcode in background and let it run in foreground while you are uploading.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26655249/1394622

Answer (score 0):

Another simple thing to try is to update the itunes Connect Form of the app version.

In my case, the builds only appeared after I've put something in the first field ("What's new in this release") and saved the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add missing items in info.plist,such as icon files, privacy usage description, requirements etc. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Wait for sometime. You can see the build. In my case it happened like that.