# Builds on iTunes Connect don't go on process

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I tried to sent builds for an iOS app on iTunes connect using Xcode 7 (final build).

But these builds are juste marked as "Downloaded" and don't go to the precessing step to validate the build.

[image: here is my problem]!

can someone help me ?

Logan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Itunes Connect: Can't See Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674742/itunes-connect-cant-see-build)

Comment: For me it seems unusual. So I suggest you co contact iTunes Connect support team. Go to Contact Us and then choose Manage your apps -> Upload Received.

Comment: I submitted a build yesterday that's been processing for almost 24 hours now. Guessing they're doing changes to the processing process after the app store malware attack https://zh.greatfire.org/blog/2015/sep/popular-chinese-ios-apps-compromised-unprecedented-malware-attack

Comment: Yeah it's like    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674742/itunes-connect-cant-see-build     but he has no answer.
Niklas : So you think i should just wait ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time apple is putting your build in queue, it take more than an hour also.  i faced same problem, and finally my build change his status after 4 hours

Comment: But i got this issue since 12 september.

Comment: oops, i think now u should try uploading new build . as per my knowledge.

Comment: I tried every day but still not working, may I can up my build version like this : 25.1 instead of 26 ?

Comment: Every build have there unique number,try to change tour build number by +1 in your build. or try by using loader

Comment: I already tried this as you can see in my pictures i tried some different up. And i can't upload again a build with same number

Comment: I tried with Application Loader 3.2 with app symbol and bitcode disable, and i tried with app symbol activated, nothing works.

Comment: did ucontact iTunes connect support centre about this issue??

Comment: Yeah they send me to Apple's forum about stuck processing (not exactly same issues). I'll try again then.

Comment: I should just wait, I guess that lot developers sent builds.