# My new app build is in iTunes Connect with status Processing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Maybe I have a stupid question, but after the update to Xcode 7, I sent a new version of my app to the App Store (via standard: Archives - Organizer - Upload to App Store). But now it is my build in iTunes Connect in tab Prerelease with status Processing (btw more than 12 hours), and I do not know why. Why is my build in Prereleasse tab? Previously, I uploaded new build the same way and  I could have it for a few minutes to submit for review. Thx for help.

**Update:** After more than 48 hours, I can finally submit my new build for review! ;-)

Comment: I have the same problem with my apps....

Comment: Patience is a virtue, plan ahead, give yourself more time than you need for app store processing and review in future.

Comment: Same problem. Android apps publishing system +1000

Comment: possible duplicate of [Itunes Connect: Can't See Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674742/itunes-connect-cant-see-build)

Comment: @Wezly I think you should realize more often than not this is Apple's fault. It consistently happens when they release a new Xcode version. And every time it happens, when I call they tell me to wait 24 hours and that build are never lost. But you know, usually the build is lost and never resurfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be related specifically to Xcode 7. Some people have mentioned these work arounds to get it to go:

1) Use Application Loader and not Xcode to submit to iTunes.

2) Re-submit with new Xcode 7.1 beta.

3) Re-submit with old Xcode 6.4.

Your milage may vary.

Edit: Problem seems to be solved now, it appears to have been related to that exploited Xcode issue in China which caused significant iTunes Connect delays.

Answer (score -2):

It's not the feature of Xcode, instead it's actually a feature of iTunes connect by itself.

All your uploaded archives go directly to "Prerelease" tab and lets you the privilege to distribute those to some specific users for beta testing, through TestFlight(optional), before you actually set it for production.

This process lets you debug your app performance and lets you actually maintain a build log, without actually releasing the app for public. When you are all set, you pick the best from Prerelease builds and release that to actual production environment, for public.

More documentation from Apple is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html)

And by the way, I think your Processing issue should be automatically resolved if you give it some time (possibly 24 hours or so) or you might need to remove your app and upload that once more. You might know, Apple is too much busy to maintain it's App Store's security, right now ;)!!!