# Send for Review iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I had enough problems uploading my application. They go more than two weeks I uploaded my application and even I can not select my binary to submit it for review. All I uploaded the binary I uploaded today XCODE and try uploading by Application Loader, I happen to have binary 1 and 4 approved "in progress"'ve tried to do everything that I find online, upload other versions but nothing has worked. Since the October 8 I try.

[image]

Comment: Dear. If itunes(Apple) will approve your binary than after you can keep it as ready for sale. And after ready for sale you can see online.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you meant.

Comment: This is a bug from Apple. You have to give them a call: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32674762/598812

Comment: I will check and make the call. Thank you for sending the other post, I read it and I became clearer.

Comment: First itunes will check your application, which is called "in progress". If your application is as per itunes standards than they will approve your binary(Application). and than after you can make it as ready for sale. And after that, you can see online.

Comment: I run into this problem every time I submit a new binary to Apple.  My solution has been to submit multiple binaries with different build numbers, usually after about an hour one of them shows up.