# iOS app "Processing" in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I uploaded my first iOS app today to iTunes Connect.
I uploaded it over xCode 7.2.1 and I see the app as "Processing" inside the "activity"-tab.
But under "AppStore"-tab for version 1.0 there is no app build visible. I only see the message that I should upload a build with xCode or Application Loader.

Is this normal or should I wait some time that the app is also showing up?

See the screenshots below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As everyone said, its normal. And if you want to get a macOS notification after the process, check out [watchbuild](https://github.com/fastlane/watchbuild)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly normal. You just have to wait for it to finish processing (can take a few minutes or a few hours depending on Apple's traffic). Once it is done processing, it will appear in that builds section and you can select it as the version you want to submit. This is the same for TestFlight.

I recommend getting [watchbuild](https://github.com/fastlane/watchbuild) and running it on your terminal so you can just get a notification on your computer when your build is done processing instead of having to keep checking App Store Connect.

Comment: thank you! can such processing also get stuck? at which time I should contact apple?

Comment: I haven't experienced it getting stuck. Sometimes you can accidentally upload the same build twice, in which it will only process one, but I think each build will eventually process. If it takes more than a few hours maybe increase the build number and try again. Also for future reference I've been experiencing faster upload times using the Application Loader over Xcode for uploading to ITC, but that may just be my personal experience

Comment: okay great news. and after pressing the button "submit for review" how long will it take till the app is in the store?

Comment: You can go here to check the apple review times. They are at one of their quickest review times yet (5 days right now) You can even check the graph on this site to see how it has been historically. It was at 14 days a few months ago so this is actually incredible. And yes this includes weekends. http://appreviewtimes.com/

Comment: I got an email when it was finished, so watchbuild not necessary.

Comment: Ya, it's normal as I had uploaded the build on 11.00 AM and the processing finished at next day at 1.46 AM.

Comment: One time I actually experience the "processing" get stuck (it was a while ago). I wait for about 2 days, it was still "processing". Contacting Apple doesn't help (at all!). In such case, you should just create another build (with increased build number of course) and submit it again. In my case second build pass through quite fast.

Comment: It's also funny to notice that "upload date" field in iTunesConnect/Activity changes by itself creating perception that processing took less time than it actually does. After 40 minutes after upload the build is still "processing", but now the "upload date" changes to the current time. Like it was not 40 minutes ago.

Comment: It's still kind of weird. I submitted 3 builds for different apps all around 1 minute apart, the first 2 were approved within minutes and the last is now on 2 hours.

Comment: Can i quit xcode.? Or can i shut down my system? During processing

Comment: 4.5 hours and counting, waiting for mine to finish "processing"...

Comment: what does "processing" mean? what is going on there -- like a special kind of compiling or something?

Answer (score 18):

It happened to me a couple of times. I just uploaded a new version (same code, just increased the version) and it was processed quite fast.

Just in case, the second time I [kept the archiving dialog in the foreground](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26655249/1121497).

[image: itunes activity]

Comment: I just did the same thing with one of my apps. The new build got processed and approved before the exact same previous submission.

Answer (score 10):

This is normal. After uploading a build, iTunes Connect performs some processing to prepare it for TestFlight Distribution and App Store distribution.

The status of the build should go to ready after some time. Sometimes, this happens as fast as 15 minutes after uploading but can sometimes take 1 hour or longer. After the processing finishes, the build will become available to select for TestFlight betas and app submission.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is perfectly normal. You just have to wait for it to finish processing (Can take a few minutes or a few hours depending on Apples traffic). Once it is done processing, it will appear in that builds section and you can select it as the version you want to submit. This is the same for testflight.

Additional from my personal experience (happened to me once and only once), if you submit the archive late at night on the last weekday or just before a public holiday, "sometimes" it might be processed on the next working day on the morning.

I'm at Indonesia (GMT +7), it is not uncommon for me to upload an archive around 7PM, and if it doesn't get processed in 15 minute, I usually just go home, and check it in the morning the next day. Because it happens a few time that if I upload too late, it get processed around 8AM the next morning.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today, i tried all of the fixes suggested and found that you need to wait till the invitations are sent out. I think the servers were just very busy when i was trying to test my app.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

**It happened to me when I export Unity iOS build and upload it to AppStore there are more than 3 days waiting but still showing processing.**

**Finally, Many search things I found that `Bitcode = NO` here is the issue on my build I have `Bitcode = YES` once you change and set to NO and upload again your build it's not showing processing and it's working properly.**