# Xcode app upload successful in Application Loader but not seen in Build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app. I user **Application Loader** and I get successful in it.

But if I go back to iTunes connect and refresh the page, the Build is empty.
What is wrong? I am stuck on this for the past 6 hours!!!
Build Image:[image: Img]

Comment: You can now see the uploaded builds in the "processing" state in the "Activity" tab

Comment: It is empty too :(

Comment: are you in janak.agarwal@gmail.com account in itunesconnect?

Comment: can you share screenshot of build tab in itunesconnect

Comment: Edited the question with build screenshot

Comment: Go to itunesconnect -> my apps -> app -> go to Activity, now check the logs here.. you will find all the details here

Comment: If you are unable to see build in activity tab also then you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784313/build-not-visible-in-itunes-connect

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities in this:

1. You are using outdated Xcode to upload. Try the latest one, because apple support stop working for old xcodes after launch of new xcode version.
2. Your permissions in plist are not available, like you may be using camera feature, photos feature, location feature but permissions are not given in plist so kindly add keys for the permissions in plist..

The best way to figure out about the issue is to check the email ID that is registered with Apple developer account, you must have received email from Apple about the missing component in code. That makes the build of application invalid, so check email first to figure out what exactly the main issue is.

It clearly states the next steps. Most of the time above 2 issues are found when build is not appearing in iTunes