# Unable to change NSCameraUsageDescription in Config.xml

Tags: ios, cordova

I have been trying to solve this issue for the last few days, as it is preventing me from deploying an update to the iOS app store. When i try one of the solutions i find and build the .ipa file, then i go and check the .plist file but the **NSCameraUsageDescription** property never shows the custom message i am trying to display.

I cant tell if i am doing it wrong as i have done almost everything i can find to solve this. So far i have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566952/cordova-info-plist-nscamerausagedescription-key-is-missing) and a few others that just change the the format to how the property is set. I have also done an upgrade to the cordova version so i could use the latest version of the camera plugin to try fix this as well.

Here is my current Config.xml file: (commented parts are other methods i have tried.)

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.devexpress.apptemplate" version="1.0" versionCode="1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <name>ApplicationTemplate</name>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000" />
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
  <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />

  <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-7.1.0' />
  <preference name='pgb-builder-version' value='1' />

  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />

  <config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="add">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  </config-file>

  <platform name="ios">
    <preference name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription">
      <string>Camera is used for uploading activation photos and profile pictures.</string>
    </config-file>
    <preference name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
      <string>Photo Library is used for uploading activation photos and profile pictures.</string>
    </config-file>
   </platform>


   <!--<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite">
    <string>Camera is used for uploading activation photos and profile pictures.</string>
  </edit-config>-->

    <!--<platform name="ios">
    <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
      <string>Camera is used for uploading activation photos and profile pictures.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="Info.plist" mode="merge">
      <string>Photo Library is used for uploading activation photos and profile pictures.</string>
    </edit-config>
  </platform>-->

  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
  <author email="email@address.com" href="address.com">Description</author>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" version="4.0.3" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="1.1.5" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.2.0" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.5.1" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" version="2.4.2" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="3.2.2" onload="true" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" version="1.1.0" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="2.1.3" source="npm" onload="true" />
  <gap:plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-market" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-appversion" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" />
  <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" />

  <access origin="*" />
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
</widget>
```

Can anybody see if i am doing anything wrong? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#ios-quirks).

You need to use the `edit-config` in `config.xml`.
Like this:

```
    <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
      <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
    </edit-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have already tried that. ill try it again to be sure.

Comment: Worked for me (ionic3)

Answer (score 0):

They changed from using config-file to edit-config in cli-7.0.1 to better align with plugin.xml (well, at least that's my theory).

Read the documentation about plugin.xml for the syntax (note: it's different from config-file!): https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its late but I think its worth answering, You need to update from the Xcode itself and add the key in the info file as

Like this [Sample code ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9CGs.png)

Now check your projects's info.plist, the code should be added there like

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>APPNAME requires access to your phone's camera for this PURPOSE.</string>
```

Now, from Xcode clean your project and build again, your app should working fine now.

I have Xcode version 10.3 and its working very fine with this solution.

Hope this help anyone!!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience changes to the config.xml file only get propagated when a platform gets added (or a plugin whose plugin.xml contains new permission/s).

In other words if you change an Android- or iOS-related permission or usage description and the change doesn't appear after you `cordova build`, `cordova emulate` or `cordova run` then you probably need to remove and re-add the appropriate platform:

- `cordova platform rm android; cordova platform add android`
- `cordova platform rm ios; cordova platform add ios`