# Build Binary not visible in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded ionic mobile app build binary file using Xcode and Application Loader. Application is successfully uploaded. But build binary not visible in itunes connect. 
My application is free application. 
I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784313/build-not-visible-in-itunes-connect) question and answers. But i was unable to solve problem.

Is there any problem with my tax and agreement in itunesconnect ?
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few possible reasons for now showing binary :

- First i would like to clear that its not relates to the agreement & tax details
- Secondly Once you upload binary from application loader or directly from Xcode it will first take some time for processing
- Now this processing time can be 5 mins or 10 mins or even a 2-3 hours.
- I am not sure why exactly it take some times hours to show binary, but it might be due to iTunes web page always been in something maintenance work going on. So this could affect it.
- I have faced such issue several times when i have waiting for 1-2 hours for appear binary for selection on iTunes connect.
- So i suggest you to wait for some time around 2 hours & still if you are not getting than contact apple support team. But i am damn sure you will get it.

I hope this will guide you.

Comment: thank you for support. But I am wating more than two days. Still not build visible in here

Comment: how to contact itunes connect support team

Comment: @ding7890 you can contact support team via this link : https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs

Answer (score 4):

Same here.

Please check your apple id email account, apple team has described how to fix it.

example from my account

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Comment: Do you use some additional features for your app suchh as camera, photo galary

Comment: No, my app has not use both but I'am already fixed and my app live on AppStore now.