# Xcode distribute archive to Apple Store: not appearing in Apple Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have distributed by xcode archive to the apple store.   It goes through all the checks, and then after 7-8 minutes it reports that everything was successful, and the app has been published to the store.

It has been 96 hours now, and when I check the apple developer console for this app, it still says there is no build included, and to click here for options on how to upload a build.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this error.  It says the upload was successful, so where did it actually go?

### Edit

Thank you so much for your responses so far guys.  The link you posted talks about the iTunes Connect store.   Can I just ask if I am in the right place?

I am on:    https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

From here I click on "My Apps" which takes me to:  https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/28762298   (this lists itunesconnect in the URL, so looks like the right place?)

Then from here I click on "Prepare For Submission".   This displays a page with all my screenshots, descriptions etc... and also this:

[image: Empty build]

This is what I am going off, and I am assuming that my Xcode distribution should appear here but it has been 4 days so far.   I have not even submitted this for review yet.   Just want to upload it to this part.

Comment: Are you aware of the review process for the App Store?

Comment: @juniorRubyist, OP does not see the build in iTunes Connect. This does not have to do with the review process.

Comment: @RashwanL got it.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784313/build-not-visible-in-itunes-connect) post which might help you.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I have edited question above in response.

Comment: Does the version of your build match the version of your app in App Store connect?